Not able to find right SQL query for requirement
I have a problem with finding the right SQL query for my program.
I basically have to use two tables: Cardboard and Production. A Cardboard has a Cardboard_Number, where the last 10 digits depict the delivery note number. I need to find a query which selects all Productions based on the input PRODUCTION_NUMBER and POSNR, find all delivery note numbers in the Production and finally find all Productions where any of the delivery note numbers was used as well. When searching the Productions based on the used delivery note numbers, I need to know every Production where it was used in, no matter when or on which line it was used.
I already have two queries which are nearly doing my work, but I'm not sure on how to modify and join them into one efficient query so it does meet my requirement. (The queries are as well included in the fiddle)
See this dbfiddle for sample data, expected output and a more detailed description.
To explain the "offset" which is used: Basically when searching for a delivery note number, I want to get all cardboards which contain this number + all cardboards which where scanned before and after each found one on the spefific production line. For a more detailed explanation see this StackOverflow thread.
Edit:
To get the connection from the Production to the delivery note number, I basically have to find all cardboards scanned between the Production_StartDT and Production_EndDT (I get the start and end with a simple select, as I have the PRODUCTION_NUMBER and POSNR as input). As already said, the last 10 digits of the Cardboard_Number does depict the delivery note number. Then I would have to find all other Productions, no matter on which production line and disregarding of the start and end, in which any of the delivery note numbers was used as well.
Sample data:

Production:

| PRODUCTION_NUMBER | POSNR |      START_DT      |        END_DT      | PRODUCTION_LINE |
| -----------------:|------:|:-------------------|:-------------------|----------------:|
|       12344       |   1   | 28-FEB-24 14.02.35 | 29-FEB-24 18.02.35 |        2        |
|       12345       |   1   | 29-FEB-24 18.22.40 | 07-MAR-24 18.22.40 |        1        |
|       12345       |   2   | 05-MAR-24 13.02.35 | 12-MAR-24 13.02.35 |        2        |
|       12345       |   2   | 14-MAR-24 14.02.35 | 16-MAR-24 13.02.35 |        2        |



Cardboard:

| CARDBOARD_NUMBER |     DATE_TIME      | PRODUCTIONLINE_NUMBER |
| :----------------|:-------------------|----------------------:|
| WDL-005943998-1  | 05-AUG-14 10.03.32 |           1           |
| spL1ml82N4o      | 29-FEB-24 17.13.54 |           1           |
| WDL-005943998-1  | 01-MAR-24 09.44.42 |           1           |
| WDL-005943998-1  | 01-MAR-24 10.34.57 |           1           |
| 950024027237     | 01-MAR-24 10.44.57 |           1           |
| 950024027237     | 01-MAR-24 10.52.57 |           1           |
| WDL-005943998-1  | 01-MAR-24 13.58.43 |           2           |
| WDL-005943998-1  | 01-MAR-24 13.58.46 |           2           |
| spL1ml82N4o      | 01-MAR-24 14.09.43 |           2           |
| WDL-005943998-1  | 12-MAR-24 11.48.36 |           2           |



Current select for returning Productions (with an offset) based on input: delivery note number = 05943998-1:

    With Cardboard_offset(cardboard_number, date_time, productionline_number) as (
        select cardboard_number, date_time, productionline_number
        from (
            SELECT cardboard_number, date_time, productionline_number,
            sum(case when Cardboard_Number like CONCAT('%', '05943998-1') then 1 else 0 end) over (
                partition by ProductionLine_Number
                order by date_time
                rows BETWEEN 1 preceding AND 1 following
            ) matches
            from cardboard
        ) table1_with_matches
        where matches > 0
    )
    SELECT distinct p.production_number,
           p.posnr,
           p.production_line,
           p.start_dt,
           p.end_dt
    FROM   production p
           INNER JOIN cardboard_offset c
           ON p.production_line = c.productionline_number
           AND c.date_time BETWEEN p.start_dt AND p.end_dt

| PRODUCTION_NUMBER | POSNR | PRODUCTION_LINE |       START_DT     |       END_DT       |
| -----------------:|------:|----------------:|:-------------------|:-------------------|
| 12345             |   1   |        1        | 29-FEB-24 18.22.40 | 07-MAR-24 18.22.40 |
| 12345             |   2   |        2        | 05-MAR-24 13.02.35 | 12-MAR-24 13.02.35 |



Current select for returning cardboards (with an offset) based on input: production_number = 12345 and posnr = 1:

    select d.cardboard_number, d.date_time, d.productionline_number
    from production a
    join lateral
    (
        select cardboard_number, date_time, productionline_number
        from (
        SELECT cardboard_number, date_time, productionline_number,
            sum(case when date_time between a.start_dt and a.end_dt then 1 else 0 end) over (
                partition by ProductionLine_Number
                order by date_time
                rows BETWEEN 1 preceding AND 1 following
            ) matches
            from cardboard
        ) table1_with_matches
        where matches > 0
    ) d on a.production_line = d.productionline_number
    where a.production_number = 12345 and a.posnr = 1

| CARDBOARD_NUMBER |      DATE_TIME     | PRODUCTIONLINE_NUMBER |
| :----------------|:-------------------|----------------------:|
| spL1ml82N4o      | 29-FEB-24 17.13.54 |           1           |
| WDL-005943998-1  | 01-MAR-24 09.44.42 |           1           |
| WDL-005943998-1  | 01-MAR-24 10.34.57 |           1           |
| 950024027237     | 01-MAR-24 10.44.57 |           1           |
| 950024027237     | 01-MAR-24 10.52.57 |           1           |



Expected output (with Input: PRODUCTION_NUMBER = 12345, POSNR = 1, Offset = 1):

12344 - 1 (because delivery note number 'pL1ml82N4o' was used in this production)
12345 - 1 (because delivery note numer '05943998-1' was used in this production)
12345 - 2 (because delivery note numer '05943998-1' was used in this production)


Hi - all questions on this forum need to be self-contained so please don't link to external sites that contain part of the information required to help you (the explanation of offsets); add this information to your question. Also, in your question you've said "find all delivery note numbers in the Production" - however there doesn't appear to be anything in the Production table that equates to a delivery note number, please can you explain this in more detail?

@NickW I updated my question and added some additional information, I hope you can find it useful.

I found a solution:
SELECT distinct p.production_number,
           p.posnr,
           p.production_line,
           p.start_dt,
           p.end_dt
from Production production
join
(
    select d.cardboard_number, d.date_time, d.productionline_number
    from production a
    join lateral
    (
        select distinct SUBSTR(d.cardboard_number, -10), date_time
        from (
        SELECT cardboard_number, date_time, productionline_number,
            sum(case when date_time between a.start_dt and a.end_dt then 1 else 0 end) over (
                partition by ProductionLine_Number
                order by date_time
                rows BETWEEN 1 preceding AND 1 following
            ) matches
            from cardboard
        ) table1_with_matches
        where matches > 0
    ) d on a.production_line = d.productionline_number
    where a.production_number = 12345 and a.posnr = 1
) ca on ca.date_time between production.start_dt and production.end_dt;

